# Template not found pyinstaller BOTTLE

Tags: python, pyinstaller, bottle

I used pyinstaller to create an executable for a bottle_app for a personal project of mine for a friend. However, after running the executable, it fails to load the template for the home page.

The console for the server only shows the following after a couple refreshes:

```
Bottle v0.12.19 server starting up (using WSGIRefServer())...
Listening on http://localhost:8080/
Hit Ctrl-C to quit

127.0.0.1 - - [02/Apr/2021 08:01:30] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 788
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Apr/2021 08:01:30] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 742
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Apr/2021 08:01:35] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 788
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Apr/2021 08:01:36] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 788
```

When I run the bottle_app.py file on my machine normally, it works fine.

Here is the command that I ran in pyinstaller

```
pyinstaller --onefile --add-data 'views/*;views' --add-data 'views/css;views/css' --add-data 'views/js;views/js'--add-data 'pricesBeef.csv;.' --add-data 'pricesHog.csv;.' --add-data 'pricesLamb.csv;.' 'bottle_app.py'
```

And here is the structure of my application

bottle_app.py 
pricesBeef.csv 
pricesLamb.csv 
pricesHog.csv 
views (folder) 
->7 html files (inside views) 
->css (folder inside of views) 
->->css file (only inside of css folder) 
->js (folder inside of views) 
->->js file (only file inside of js folder)

I'm not getting any traceback errors, which is what's the weird part to me.

Comment: Update: I switched to auto-py-to-exe and using it will still fail if i do --onefile, if I run --onedir, it will work, but defeats the point as I would still need to install python on the user's machine to support the .pyd files in the directory.

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer but a workaround

Use `--onedir` instead of `--onefile` and simply use a shortcut to the executable. It will work without needing python already installed, even with .pdy files in the directory